# Running python from a mounted filesystem

Tags: python, django, virtualbox, vagrant

I have a django-based application that I'm running from a virtualbox-shared folder. When starting using 'runserver' I get an error indicating that a module could not be found. After copying the same exact code to a directory on the local filesystem, it starts and runs as expected.

Anyone seen anything like this when working with virtualbox and python?

It appears that module resolution is working differently when python is run from the mounted shared folder vs. the local folder, but I can't find a smoking gun that indicates whether or not it's caused by how that folder is mounted or python.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have django installed on the VM?  How about having PATH set up properly on the VM?

Comment: Yes, everything is setup properly. I do a simple cp -R of the app directory and start it from a local directory (not shared folder) and it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try avoid putting your projects (large number of files/directories) on `vboxsf` (default synced folder).

`vboxsf` lacks support for symbolic / hard links, which will potentially cause problems (e.g. using git as version control). see the ticket [#818](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/818) here, it is still NOT fixed.

Answer (score 0):

There is a chance you're running into a problem with file system case sensitivity. It took me a couple of hours to figure this out myself. The shared folder is case insensitive, but the local folders are case sensitive since they are on a different file system (ext3/4). So you'll run into problems where python files in your current directory will override an import of the same name.

A simple example with pycrypto showing this (`pip install pycrypto` if you dont have it):

```
vagrant@virtualos:/mnt/shared_folder$ python -c 'from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA'
vagrant@virtualos:/mnt/shared_folder$ touch crypto.py
vagrant@virtualos:/mnt/shared_folder$ python -c 'from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named PublicKey
```

If I do the same thing on a local (ext4) directory it works fine. It seems python has different import logic depending on what OS it is running on.

Unfortunately I have not found a good solution to this other than to manually copy files onto my VM instead of using shared folders.

Answer (score 0):

One solution I found was to mount my shared folder with cifs into the VM. That seems to work flawlessly. I did not found a solution for the vboxsf.